# /etc/sudoers in vagrant box not being persisted

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm not seeing changes made to /etc/sudoers persisted from one virtualbox to another.

In base Vagrantfile I package a "base.box" which has changes made to /etc/sudoers
So when I vagrant ssh, I see the changes fine.

In another Vagrantfile I build off the "base.box" via

```
config.vm.box = "base"
config.vm.box_url = "../base.box"
```

This builds fine, but when I vagrant ssh.  The changes made to /etc/sudoers are lost from the base.

I have uploaded both Vagrant Files... base/Vagrantfile and second/Vagrantfile

https://gist.github.com/joshuacalloway/5192401a1eeb287fc4aa

Comment: Fixed see comments. below.  Some reason Vagrant is using cached vagrant box base even though I had url listed as "vm.box_url = '../base.box'"

Comment: did u solve ur problem..i had encounter same problem

Answer (score 0):

The changes you make on one vagrant box will not persist to the next, the changes do not get saved to base.box rather an instance of it.

If you want to make your own base.box that will persist changes take a look at https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html

Comment: I did package the base.box with the changes.  so it should have been saved

Comment: How did you build the box, with virtual box?  It sounds like your taking base.box running it with a vagrant file then trying to build a box from that, thats not how it works.  You need to make a VM customize it then convert it to a vagrant base box.

Comment: I built base.box with vagrant.    1) cd base;vagrant up;vagrant package --base base --output ../base.box

Comment: @jcalloway That won't work take a look at these instructions for creating a base box https://github.com/fespinoza/checklist_and_guides/wiki/Creating-a-vagrant-base-box-for-ubuntu-12.04-32bit-server

Comment: I'm not following.  The base box that I built, I can re use in the secondary box.  It has puppet installed.  So of course I'm seeing some things as expected.  What I am not seeing is changes to /etc/sudoers

Comment: ok when you edited /etc/sudoers, did you do it in a vagrant shell like this: vagrant ssh, vim /etc/sudoers?

Comment: I figured it out.  even though I had the box_url listed as vm.box_url = "../base.box",  I still had to do a vagrant box remove base prior.